# (Failed to save settings. Please restart IntelliJ IDEA) error after dowloading intellij idea 2020.2 and importing a project made in 2020.1

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I receive a "Failed to save settings. Please restart IntelliJ IDEA" error after dowloading Intellij Idea 2020.2 and importing a Maven project made in 2020.1 even after restarting intellij over and over. I have no plugins installed but the default ones. Did anyone have this error? I tried to delete the .idea file but the same error appears. Thanks in advance

Comment: sounds like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-242881, could you please share an idea.log (Help | Show log...)?